# Calculate distance between center of the circle at Edge

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

How can i Calculate Distance between center of the circle and extreme edges.

Below is the sample image and the green line is the Distance which i want to calculate.

[image]

**How can do this using Open CV?**

Comment: Threshold the image on the black color and then do hough circle on that. You should get a circle at the edges of the blades, which will tell you the center and radius.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Not easy to make this reliably. In the first place, make sure that you take the picture in front, to avoid parallax errors.

Possibly find the central circle(s) by Hough. This gives you the center.

Now the hard par is to segment the blades. Possibly by thresholding on a luminance image or anything close to that cream color. Or using a general segmentation method.

Then figure out which blade is segmented most accurately, and find the longest distance from the center to any point of the blade (that gives you the tip).

---

If you don't care about accuracy, it is not impossible that Hough gives you the outer circle.